# Swift: Initializer 'init(_:rowContent:)' requires that 'HealthStat' conform to 'Identifiable'

Tags: swift, xcode, watchos, identifiable

I'm receiving an error from Xcode that my List:

```
List(viewModel.stats) { stat in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(viewModel.value(from: stat.stat).desc)
            Text(stat.date, style: .date).opacity(0.5)
        }
```

Is not conforming to Identifiable:

`Initializer 'init(_:rowContent:)' requires that 'HealthStat' conform to 'Identifiable'`

I looked at my HealthStat File

```
import Foundation
import HealthKit


struct HealthStat {
    let id = UUID()
    let stat: HKQuantity?
    let date: Date
}
```

I have the stat declared, so I'm not sure why it's giving out to me. I'm fairly new to Swift so it's probably something I overlooked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
struct HealthStat
```

To

```
struct HealthStat: Identifiable
```

Protocol adoption is not some accidental quality that accrues implicitly because a type happens to match the protocol requirements. It's all about explicit declaration of the type. If you don't *say* your type adopts a protocol, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

IF you don't want to explicitly make it `Identifiable`, you can also use this pattern:

```
List(viewModel.stats, id: \.self.id ) { stat in ....
```

This should work as well.